# Does ionic 1 angularjs code run on ionic 2?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am migrating from **Ionic 1.x** to **Ionic 2.x**. In Ionic we used **AngularJS 1.x.x**.

Now I am mostly reusing the same code in **Ionic 2.x** and have not faced any issues. Is there anything that I should keep in mind while migrating as `Ionic 2` is written in `AngularJS 2`.

My code is still in **Angular 1**. Though it works is it a good thing to do? Is there something that I need to be aware of?

Comment: angular 1 and angular 2 are not the same framework;  angular 2 was rewritten from the ground up.  There are *some* possible upgrade paths, but you will likely be rewriting a large portion of your code, especially if you rely upon angular 1 features like `$scope` which don't exist in angular 2.

Comment: @Claies But I am currently using `$scope` in **ionic 2** and it is working.

Comment: doubtful;  you may have installed the ionic 2 cli, but if you didn't use `--v2` when creating the new project, you're still using ionic 1, and if you did use the v2 switch, using `$scope` wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Claies Yeah you are right. I just checked and am in version 1.6. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is **NO**.

Any code that has been written in **AngularJS 1.x.x** will not ideally run in **Ionic 2**, unless you add angular in your library separately.

So ideally you should have **Angular 1** with **Ionic 1**, and **Angular 2** with **Ionic 2**.